# WP_Query - How to query all of post types categories

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I added a custom taxonomy to woocommerce's `products` post type. The custom taxonomy is called `Brands` and is simply used to select the brand of the product.

I am using `wp_query` to query all of the brands so that I may click them and get all of the products that associate. I just cant figure out how to query all of the brands for a given post type.

Here is my attempted query which isnt returning anything:

```
    $brands = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query'     => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'brands',
                'field'     => 'name',
                ),
            ),
        );
$query = new WP_Query( $brands );
```

Comment: In your question you state "Brands" but in your code it's "brands".  That could be it.

Comment: You first need to fetch all taxonomy terms. You can do that using the following function:
`$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'brands'
) );`
Then based on your brand page you can get the taxonomy id on the term page using `get_queried_object()->term_id;` and then you will need your tax query on the term page to be `'tax_query'     => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'brands',
                'terms'     => get_queried_object()->term_id,
                ),
            ),`